# How to share a common file in all lambda functions

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have some lambda functions(node.js) in AWS, that will connect to postgresql and doing some query and get the results back, so i am trying to make one configuration file for database which has the user, password, database name, port ... So what will be the best way to share a common configuration file to all lambda function?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/env_variables.html

Comment: @JackRyan this i have to update in every lambda function, if i have any change in my db configuration then i have to go to every lambda function and change right? i am looking something  like when i change in one place that will give effect in all lambda functions.

Answer (score 2):

AWS Provides two services for this purpose.

1. [AWS Secrets Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-secrets-manager-store-distribute-and-rotate-credentials-securely/)
2. [AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-paramstore.html)

AWS Secrets Manager is the latest service which has version controlled secrets and automatically rotates keys.

You can either store is as individual keys or combine all keys, store them as one key.

**Secrets Manager Example:**

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SecretsManager.html#getSecretValue-property

```
var params = {
  SecretId: "MyTestDatabaseSecret", 
  VersionStage: "AWSPREVIOUS"
 };
 secretsmanager.getSecretValue(params, function(err, data) {
   if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
   else     console.log(data);           // successful response
   /*
   data = {
    ARN: "arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-west-2:123456789012:secret:MyTestDatabaseSecret-a1b2c3", 
    CreatedDate: <Date Representation>, 
    Name: "MyTestDatabaseSecret", 
    SecretString: "{\n  \"username\":\"david\",\n  \"password\":\"BnQw&XDWgaEeT9XGTT29\"\n}\n", 
    VersionId: "EXAMPLE1-90ab-cdef-fedc-ba987SECRET1", 
    VersionStages: [
       "AWSPREVIOUS"
    ]
   }
   */
 });
```

**Systems Manager Parameter Store:**

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SSM.html#getParameter-property

```
var params = {
  Name: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
  WithDecryption: true || false
};
ssm.getParameter(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

**EDIT1:**

For sharing common files from a common storage, it is not possible as now. You can store the file in s3 and pull from there. It is going to have a heavy cold start.

Comment: i have checked this 'Secrets Manager' here do we need to create key separately for every function right? we have to choose which lambda function right?

Comment: now i tried to create a JSON file in s3 and read values from there in every lambda function, so i can upload the file and that will give effect to all function. is that a right approach?

Comment: Secrets manager and system manager parameter, if you read the documentation correctly and follow the code, it will be able to share the configuration across all lambda. If you drop it to S3 and read from there you are reinventing the wheel.

Comment: This is very helpful for the specific case but does not answer the question that was asked. I suspect the actual answer in the case of trying to share a JavaScript code file is “No” but would like that confirmed.

Comment: @JaneNicholson If you want to share files, AWS Lambda is introduced with Layers which can share code between lambas. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html . Also the  OPS is trying to solve the problem with incorrect architecture and it is also fixed in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to share common files between different Lambda Functions using  [Layers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html#configuration-layers-path). You can create a zip file for the Layer pretty much the same way you do that for a Function.

The layer package will look more or less like this:

```
your-lambda-layer.zip
└ nodejs/node_modules/shared-package
```

In the code it can be referenced like this:

```
const shared = require('shared-package');
```

The `shared-package` can contain your code or configurations.

Answer (score 1):

Define your shared code in a [AWS Lambda Layer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html) using `AWS::Lambda::LayerVersion` or `AWS::Serverless::LayerVersion` and then reference to it in your lambda functions. For example with [AWS SAM](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model) :

```
  MyFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: function_code/
      Handler: app.lambda_handler
      Runtime: nodejs8.10
      Layers:
        - !Ref MySharedLayer
  MySharedLayer:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::LayerVersion
    Properties:
      LayerName: SharedLayerName
      Description: Some shared code
      ContentUri: layer_code/
      CompatibleRuntimes:
        - nodejs8.10
      LicenseInfo: 'My License'
      RetentionPolicy: Retain
```

The layer code will be available in the `/opt` folder and can be included in your lambda functions.

Comment: how do I deploy my common layer zip using pipelines?